The iText paragraph is superimposed on a previously saved paragraph
I need to set the text with a certain font and size in a certain place, so I considered StampAnnotation not suitable, because I did not see where and how to install my font. The problem is that after creating a paragraph and spacing the text, you may need to change it, but instead of spacing a new value, it turns out that the text overlaps ("25шт" overlapped with "363936393639шт", but moreover in Adobe Acrobate Pro this text is defined as a single paragraph)
image
I put the value in the following way:
var font = PdfFontFactory.CreateFont("C:\\Windows\\Fonts\\GOST Common.ttf", "Identity-H");
        _workingDocument.SetFont(font);

string utf8String = count + "шт.";
        var writableText = new Paragraph(utf8String).SetItalic().SetBold();

switch (_format)
        {
            case Formats.A4Book:
                x = 530;
                y = 175;
                ClearText(text, x, y); //I'm trying to delete a value usingPdfCleaner.AutoSweepCleanUp
                AddImage(x, y); //I present a picture that overlaps a part of another text that is not cleared and should not be in the ClearText method
                writableText.SetFontSize(20).SetFixedPosition(x - 300, y, 350).SetTextAlignment(TextAlignment.RIGHT)
                    .SetHorizontalAlignment(HorizontalAlignment.RIGHT);
                _workingDocument.Add(writableText);
                break;
            case Formats.A3Album:
                ... // The same thing, but the other x and y
            case Formats.A3Book:
                ... // The same thing, but the other x and y
            default:
                ...
        }

Cleaning logic:
int countTry = 0;
ICleanupStrategy cleanupStrategy =
            new RegexBasedCleanupStrategy(new Regex(@"(.*)[0-9]{1,}(.*)шт(.*)", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase))
                .SetRedactionColor(ColorConstants.WHITE);
while (countTry < 3)
{
     try
     {
            PdfCleaner.AutoSweepCleanUp(_document.GetFirstPage(), cleanupStrategy);
     }
     catch
     {
            // ignore
     }
     finally
     {
             countTry++;
     }
}

I have version iText 8.0.5, iText.pdf sweep 4.0.3, itext.bouncy-castle-adapter 8.0.5, .Net 8

So your problem is what exactly? That the cleanup logic does not work as intended?

@mkl Yes, AutoSweepCleanUp does not work. Maybe there is a solution to get an existing paragraph in pdf or not to write a new paragraph to an existing one (and it writes new data to an existing paragraph and makes an inter-letter interval of -50), or put your own font in PdfStamp

The PDF format at its core doesn't know paragraphs. It only knows glyphs and sequences of them drawn in a row as far as text is concerned. (Yes, PDFs may be tagged with structure, but that is optional and if it's there, it's not what processors see at first.) Thus, you cannot get an existing paragraph or write new data to an existing paragraph. I think you should use an annotation, e.g. a stamp, but explicitly create its appearance stream and draw to it using a PdfCanvas or a Canvas which allows you to use any fonts you want.

The problem turned out to be that the System.Drawing.Common was installed implicitly and was outdated, as a result, the explicit installation of 9.0.0 helped solve some of the cleaning problems, but alas, the text is still not deleted on all files
